# Recalculate Google Maps Direction if take the wrong lane

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, map-directions

I use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 for calculating the directions from my current position to my end destination in an iPad PhoneGap Application.

Now I want to make a function which automatically recalculates the directions, if you take the wrong lane. That means, I will make a marker for the current position on the map and then should check if it's near the directions-polygon, if not recalculate the route.

The directions are printed out in a canvas-element and I couldn't find anything how to compare it with my markers…

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line works. Just set the tolerance as desired.

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge (point, polyline, tolerance)
```

It will return true if point is located in the polyline/ polygen. Let me know if tyhis doesn't work.

axs